# Next/previous line in a dataset without using a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, dataset

Does anyone have an idea of how to refer to the next/previous line in a dataset without using a loop (in MATLAB) ?

What I am trying to do is to find the rows where the a value in one line is the same as the value in the same column in the previous line, and how many times it has been so.

Usually, I would use a loop, so for example:-

```
for n = 2:100
   if Dataset.Value(n) == Dataset.Value(n-1)
      Dataset.Repeat(n) = 1
   end
end
```

But the files I have range in the tens of thousands of rows, and it takes too much time to go through it all that way, so is there a way I could do it without using a loop?

Something like:

```
Dataset.Repeat(Dataset.Value(current_line) == Dataset.Value(previous_line)) = 1;
```

Except I don't think there is a previous_line command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [diff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html) command. Something like

```
find(diff(Dataset.Value)==0)
```

should give you the indexes of repeated values (you might need to add 1 to point to the repeated element as in your code).

EDIT: actually I think what you want is `Dataset.Repeat = [0 diff(Dataset.Value)==0 ];`, where the concatenation with 0 is to shift to indicate the second of the repeated elements rather than the first.